# Displaying Google Maps in Unity on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to display Google Maps (even other maps should be ok) in Unity 3D but on mobile devices (both Android and iOS)?

Even paid plugins are ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Unity's [WWW.texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html) and Google's [static maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example) to render their map as a texture on a GameObject.  For my example I used a plane, nothing fancy.  The image URL I used in my example was taken directly from the Google API page.  One note, you'll need to use your own [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#api_key), I've left that value blank.  If you run my example without the API key, you'll get a 403 error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GoogleMaps : MonoBehaviour {

string exampleUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,"+
                    "New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794"+
                    "&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318"+
                    "&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284"+
                    "&sensor=false";
string key = "&key=YOUR_API_KEY"; //put your own API key here.

 IEnumerator Start() {
    WWW www = new WWW(exampleUrl+key);
    yield return www;
    renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
}
}
```

Comment: This is rather interesting. However, what if we want to make a constant update like the real GPS? For example if we feed it Longtitude and Latitude.

Comment: If you'd like a map to move with GPS you'd need a "Slippy map". Here's one: https://github.com/jderrough/UnitySlippyMap

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I started to work on [map based framework](https://github.com/ActionStreetMap/demo) for unity3d: ActionStreetMap. The current version (0.7) supports the following features:

- Rendering of different models (e.g. buildings, roads, parks, rivers,POI, etc.) using OpenStreetMap (OSM) data for given location on the fly by terrain tiling approach.
- Offline and online modes.
- Non-flat terrain with Data Elevation Model (SRTM)  files.
- Easy customization by [mapcss](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapCSS)-like files.
- Modification of city environment (terrain craters, corrupt buildings, etc..).
- Fast 2D overview mode for large area.
- Targeting mobile (VR?) devices.

You can find web demo builds [here](http://actionstreetmap.github.io/demo/).

Answer (score 0):

My plugin Google Maps View does exactly this: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/google-maps-view-82542

Works on Android and on iOS. It is a native view so the performance is great. The only limitation is that you can't display Unity scene objects on top of it.